# database is not updating despite the db.insert function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, knex.js

I'm making a forgot password functionality in my express app suing node mailer package which sends a new password to the email of the user and then updating the database with the new password but the problem is that the database is not updating with the new password i have reviewed my code many times but unable to figure out the problem.

```
`app.post('/forgot', (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  let newPassword = generatePassword();
  db.select('*').from('login')
  .where('email', '=', email)
  .returning('*')
  .then(user => {
    if (user.length > 0) {
      let mailOptions = {
        from: 'haroonrmit@gmail.com', 
        to: `${email}`, 
        subject: 'Password reset', 
        html: `<p>Your new password is ${newPassword}</p>`
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      db('login')
      .where({email: user[0].email})
      .update({
        password: newPassword
      })
      res.json(user[0]);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json('email not found');
    }
  })
});`
```

Comment: sorry for the typo its db.update im using postgresql

Comment: whats the difference between .where('email', '=', email) and .where({email: user[0].email}). are'nt they both different way of doing same thing?

Comment: yeah it has multiple syntaxes for doing the same thing

Comment: Have you tried any debugging ... `.update({
        password: newPassword
      }).then(v => console.log(v, 'records updated')).catch(err => console.error('error updating password:', err))`

Comment: but im unable to figure out why the database is not updating with the new password

Comment: yes it giving '' 1 'records updated' '' message in the console

Comment: how odd - I take it other database updates in your code work just fine?

Comment: its working now i just added a returning('*') after the .then and its being updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling .then for the second query, so it is built but never ran.

Also your http returns a value before it knows if update was executed with success.